# How to use Wine-devel to install OpenBUGS on Catalina?

Tags: catalina, install, homebrew, wine

My MacBook Air: Catalina 10.15.4 (19E287)

I have already installed `Homebrew`. However, as `Wine` still requires 32-bit code to run 32-bit Windows software, while Catalina dropped 32-bit code support, I installed `Wine-devel` instead (following the last answer in [How to get Wine working on Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373851/how-to-get-wine-working-on-catalina/380068#380068?newreg=553f3ccca2fd48f1afd0f8c215a1d070)).

I especially paid attention to the **NOTE** in that answer, so I removed my original `~/.wine` folder.

Then I downloaded Windows version of `OpenBUGS` [here](https://www.mrc-bsu.cam.ac.uk/training/short-courses/bayescourse/download/).

In terminal, I typed `wine64 ~/Downloads/OpenBUGS323setup.exe`, it shows:

```
(base) DengdeMacBook-Air:~ deng$ wine64 ~/Downloads/OpenBUGS323setup.exe
001b:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
0020:err:plugplay:runloop_thread Couldn't open IOHIDManager.
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"Z:\\Users\\deng\\Downloads\\OpenBUGS323setup.exe" not supported on this system
(base) DengdeMacBook-Air:~ deng$ wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF at address 00007FFF37F26E16 (thread 001c), starting debugger...
001c:err:seh:start_debugger Couldn't start debugger L"winedbg --auto 24 96" (1115)
Read the Wine Developers Guide on how to set up winedbg or another debugger
```

and just stuck here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the 32 in `OpenBUGS323setup` stand for the version number or does it indicate 32bit software?

Comment: @nohillside Well... No. I think it just means 3.2.3 version