# How to install 64-bit Wine on macOS Catalina

Tags: wine

I first read [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373851/how-to-get-wine-working-on-catalina) question and was able to install Wine as follows:

```
brew install homebrew/cask-versions/wine-devel
```

I then downloaded the 64 bit version of Notepad++ [here](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) and attempted to install it as follows:

```
wine64 install npp.8.1.4.Installer.x64.exe //1. didn't work
wine64 npp.8.1.4.Installer.x64.exe //2. didn't work
```

What am I missing?

The error messages are as follows:

Error 1:

```
001b:err:ntoskrnl:ZwLoadDriver failed to create driver L"\\Registry\\Machine\\System\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\wineusb": c0000142
000f:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1114
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"C:\\windows\\system32\\install.exe" not found
```

Error 2:

```
0031:err:module:__wine_process_init L"Z:\\Users\\j\\Downloads\\npp.8.1.4.Installer.x64.exe" not supported on this system
```

Comment: Have you tried with the zip or 7z version of Notepad++ ?? - I think you should be able to just open Notepad++ directlly from the unzipped folder.

Comment: And another issue that you also need to be aware of: "Wine won't work on macOS Catalina 10.15" https://wiki.winehq.org/MacOS